# Does Blood Sun keep me from turning my Zoetic Cavern face up?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Zoetic Cavern](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=442238) lose its morph ability when face-down keeping it from being able to turn face-up when there is a [Blood Sun](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439749) in play?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a ruling on Zoetic Cavern that states:

> If Blood Moon is on the battlefield and a player controls a face-down Zoetic Cavern, it can’t be turned face up since it won’t have a morph cost.

This ruling comes from rule [702.36e](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Morph), which states among other things:

> If the permanent wouldn’t have a morph cost if it were face up, it can’t be turned face up this way.

So the Sun stops your Cavern from being turned face up.

Comment: Wow, I did not expect that ruling. Learn something new every day!