# Does Humility prevent Manifested creatures from being turned face-up?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-face-down-cards

Related to [Does Humility stop all creatures from being able to morph?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/44745/does-humility-stop-all-creatures-from-being-able-to-morph): The question specifies morphs, but I wondered if this was true for Manifest as well? As Manifest is not an ability on the card, does [Humility](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHumility%5d) prevent it from being turned face up for its mana cost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still turn a Manifested card face up even if it would lose all abilities from a card like Humility.

This is actually called out explicitly in a ruling on Manifest cards:

> Unlike a face-down creature that was cast using the morph ability, a manifested creature may still be turned face up after it loses its abilities if it’s a creature card. (2014-11-24)

This is because the thing that lets you turn a Manifested card face-up is not an ability on the card itself that it would lose. Instead, the thing that lets you turn a Manifested card face-up is [the Manifest rules themselves](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Manifest#Rules), which just say you can turn it face-up for its mana cost any time you have priority.

Comment: The answer is obviously very good; but there are several details which have been underestimated here, and should be rediscussed. For this, in my opinion there are many more details in the duplicate question "Why can a manifested creature be turned face up if it loses all it's abilities but a morphed card can't? [Duplicate]", especially in the comments at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Otherwise, it is not clear how a 2/2 vanilla may "lose all its abilities": how can it do it, if it is true that a vanilla has no abilities by definition? It is clear that something here is missing; there are precise connections, which are unclear here, between the moment a card loses its abilities, and the moment it is unmorphed.